# Store data into Variables PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables

I want to store these data retrieved in individual variables and send it as an SMS. There you will see one 'p_contact' database field, which will hold my Phone numbers to send SMS to. Code is as follows, just help me to store these data into individual variables:

```
<table id="highlight" class="sortable noborder" width="950">
                <caption>
                    Manage Marks of Students of 
                    <b><?php echo $database->getColumn(TBL_CLASS, 'class', $class); ?></b>
                </caption>

                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Student Code</th>
                    <th>Student Name</th>
                    <?php 
                        $subquery = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_SUBJECT." WHERE `id` IN(SELECT `subject` FROM ".TBL_SUBJECTCLASS." WHERE `class`='".$class."')";
                        $subresult = $database->query($subquery);
                        while($subrow = mysql_fetch_array($subresult)):
                    ?>
                        <th><?php echo $subrow['subject'];?></th>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </tr>
                <thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php 
                            $stdquery = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_STUDENT." WHERE `classid`='".$class."' ORDER BY `id`";
                            $stdresutl = $database->query($stdquery);
                            while($stdrow=mysql_fetch_array($stdresutl)):
                        ?>
                        <tr class="<?php echo $numrow % 2 == 0 ? 'altRowEven' : 'altRowOdd'; ?>">
                            <td id="center" class="bold">
                                <?php echo $numrow += 1; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="bold">
                                <?php echo $stdrow['stdcode']; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="bold">
                                <?php echo $stdrow['name']; ?>
                            </td>
                            <?php 
                            $subjquery = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_SUBJECT." WHERE `id` IN(SELECT `subject` FROM ".TBL_SUBJECTCLASS." WHERE `class`='".$class."')";
                            $subjresult = $database->query($subjquery);
                            while($subjrow = mysql_fetch_array($subjresult)):?>
                            <td id="padding">
                                <?php
                                    $query = "SELECT `marks` FROM ".TBL_MARK." WHERE `subject`='".$subjrow['id']."' and `stdid` = '".$stdrow['id']."'";
                                    $result = $database->query($query);
                                    $value = mysql_fetch_row($result)[0];
                                    echo $value;
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <?php endwhile?>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the 'p_contact' field, it will be just under 'echo $stdrow['name']' as 'echo $stdrow['p_contact']' because the field is already in the table.

Comment: You forgot the question. Also you're still using the **deprecated** mysql extension of PHP. It's highly recommended to migrate to MySQLi or PDO. I recommend PDO because it has a better Integration of **Prepared Statements**.

Comment: Could you please help me on how to go with it? Or you can also help me to modify the existing Code and solve my problem.

Comment: No one is answering my question... :(